# PDO_OCI: could not find driver

Tags: ubuntu, pdo, php, oracle-call-interface

Today my problem is connected with PDO, OCI8 and PDO_OCI. But from the beginning.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and PHP version: 5.3.8-1ubuntu3. I have installed Oracle 10g Express, configured it and it works fine. The next step I had to do was integration between Oracle and PDO. So I found this link: http://lacot.org/blog/2009/11/03/ubuntu-php5-oci8-and-pdo_oci-the-perfect-install.html and do it step by step (without instaling PDO, which was installed previously with pdo_mysql). When I tried to do it on Ubuntu 10.10 - it was working. Now, on 11.10 I get an error: 'Could not find driver' when I try to open my website application.

I checked phpinfo() and in the row PDO there are: PDO support - enabled, PDO drivers - mysql. There is nothing about oci in this section, although few lines under it I have PDO Driver for OCI 8 and later - enabled.

Hope somebody can help with this.
Best regards, Mateo.

Comment: Does your apache/php env have the ORACLE_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Yes. It is set into: /opt/instantclient_10_2/ (after the steps I have done during the OCI8 and PDO_OCI instalation).

Comment: Okey - I'm sure it's something with PDO. When I did all the steps from the tutorial (including instalation PDO-1.0.3) - it started to work, but another error appears ( which I mentioned in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772586/324-no-response-error-in-ubuntu-10-04-but-works-in-windows ). But when I paste previous file pdo.so - it stoped and again I saw error 'Could not find driver'.

I don't know what to do with it. :(

Comment: Do you have enabled your pdo_mysql module? Usually this error comes when `PDO_PGSQL` driver isn't loaded. Also, are your pdo extensions from `php.ini` file (`php_pdo_mysql`/`php_pdo_sqlite`) present? Even thought it appears on `phpinfo()`, you should double check it.

Comment: Have a look at this guide:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html
It worked for me. 
It could be the ORACLE_HOME variable that is not set correctly.
Try to do: echo $ORACLE_HOME

Comment: What architecture are you running this on? I had the same problem because I used the precompiled binaries that were compiled for x86 on a x86_64 installation, so php would fail to load them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile PHP with support for PDO_OCI:

```
--with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr,10.2.0.3
```

Of course, replaces the instant client version with the one you have installed.

PDO is an access type. MySQL and OCI are database types. If you installed the base PDO package, you still need to install the drivers. Drivers do not ship with PDO by default. When you installed PDO MySQL, PDO OCI was not installed as it is a separate module.